# Undefined Reference? But I've implemented the function

Tags: c, windows, winapi, function-pointers, undefined-reference

### The Code

**window.h**

```
typedef struct
{
    WNDCLASS* wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    WNDPROC proc;
} PRO_Window;

PRO_Window* PRO_WindowCreate(int width, int height, const char* title);
```

**window.c**
<sub>I don't think this is important though...</sub>

```
PRO_Window* PRO_WindowCreate(int width, int height, const char* title) { /* code */ }
```

**main.c**

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR CmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    PRO_Window* win = PRO_WindowCreate( 300, 300, "STATIC");
    return 0;
}
```

### The Error

#### GCC

```
main.o:main.c|| undefined reference to `PRO_WindowCreate(int, int, char const*)'|
```

<sub>* Reduced it to SSCCE</sub> 
<sub>* I am using the windows api</sub>

Comment: Did you #include "window.h" in main.c file?

Comment: The error with Boarland-C compiler seems to be because of the declaration of `wc` after the `wnd->proc = NULL;`.

Try to move declaration above initialization statement...

Comment: @ebutusov yes. I included that.

Comment: @Mallik thanks! you solved the Borland problem. But GCC is still spitting the `undefined reference` error. :(

Comment: great..!! Can you try declaring your `PRO_WindowCreate` extern and see if there is any success??

Comment: -1 not the real code, at least not at first. to the OP: please google and teach yourself how to COPY AND PASTE.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf lol, ok. It's `CTRL+C` + `CTRL+V` right?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker, can you update your question with the exact answer you are seeing with gcc. The definition or declaration uses const char * but the error is char const *.

Comment: @Mallik wait a sec. your previous suggestion worked with a slight modification. just copy + paste it into the answer box and get an accept and an upvote. thanks. :)

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: You're really using Borland C? That thing is from 1992 or something ridiculously old like that.

Comment: Did you remember to include window.c in your project?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker Is your question answered now?

Comment: @RaymondChen The OP has accepted one of the answers, so I'm not sure this topic is still open.

Comment: -1. If the answer is really what you say it is, then what you've posted here is *not* an SSCCE. There is no `wnd->proc = NULL` line in your code. And furthermore, there are no `#include` directives in your code, so you should expect a lot more errors than just the one you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error with Boarland-C compiler seems to be because of the declaration of `wc` after the `wnd->proc = NULL;`. Try to move declaration above initialization statement...

Answer (score 1):

The .h file doesn't have `const`, while the .c file does.

Comment: +1, sorry about that. that was just a typo I made while submitting the question. that's not the real problem.

Comment: Oh... Sorry about that. Tell me, are they compiler or linker errors?

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration (in window.h):

```
PRO_Window* PRO_WindowCreate(int width, int height, char* title);
```

is different then definition (window.c):

```
PRO_Window* PRO_WindowCreate(int width, int height, const char* title)
```

Note the last argument.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601925/undefined-reference-but-ive-implemented-the-function/9602000#comment12179588_9601962). take +1 as an apology for my typo.

Comment: Could you post the command line you are using to compile and link your program with gcc ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a GCC linking error, but you're not showing the command line used to compile, so it's hard to tell.

Also, you seem to be missing to `#include` the header in both the C files.

Comment: well, I'm using Code::Blocks to compile with GCC using the `-g` and `-Wall` options. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

You should `#include "window.h"` file in both in the implementation and the user of the PRO_WindowCreate function.